# Алгоритм поиска в глубину

Tags: c, графы

Не получается результат алгоритма на языке C, выводит: 1 - 2, на этом - все. Может, я чего-то не понимаю?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N 7

int i,j;
int visit[N];
int adjacencyMatrix[N][N] = 
{
    {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0},
    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}
};

void SetToZero(int *arr, size_t length) {
    for(i=0; i<length; i++)
        arr[i] = 0;
}
void DFC(int startVertice) {
    printf("%i ",startVertice+1);
    visit[startVertice] = 1;
    for (i = 0; i<N;i++) {
        if(adjacencyMatrix[startVertice][i] != 0 && visit[i] == 0)
            DFC(i);
    }
}

int main() {
    int startVertice;
    SetToZero(visit,N);
    printf("Начальная вершина: ");
    scanf("%i", &startVertice);

    printf("Обход:\n");
    DFC(startVertice-1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Исправил условие (приоритеты) - но ничего это не изменило.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас объявлена глобальная `i`, и она перезаписывается в каждом вызове рекурсии, вам нужно объявлять новую переменную `i` непосредственно в цикле

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
// ....
```

таким образом у каждого уровня рекурсии будет своя, независимая от других `i`